# how can I count transactions based on datetime

Tags: text-processing

my file format is below

```
123456 2016-07-05 08:08:00
123456 2016-07-05 10:23:45
125678 2016-07-05 09:23:54
127890 2016-07-06 10:23:00
127890 2016-07-06 13:00:00
```

how can I get just transactions that are only morning and afternoon?

once I get unique transactions for morning & afternoon,
 I need to get a count of how many. a unique transaction is a transaction that occurs in the morning and evening for an individual.

Comment: morning - 00:00:01 - 11:59:59 afternoon - 12:00:00 23:59:59

Comment: In the file posted, a unique transaction would be 
127890 2016-07-06 10:23:00
127890 2016-07-06 13:00:00

Comment: What if `127890` is a "unique" (why not picking another term like "valid") transaction in a different day too ? Does that add to the count when counting the number of "unique" transactions ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work...

To get the "morning" values:

```
egrep ' 0[0-9]:| 1[0-1]:' transactions | sort -u -k1,1
123456 2016-07-05 08:08:00
125678 2016-07-05 09:23:54
127890 2016-07-06 10:23:00
```

To get the "evening" ones:

```
egrep ' 1[2-9]:| 2[0-3]:' transactions | sort -u -k1,1
127890 2016-07-06 13:00:00
```

If you want to count them:

```
egrep ' 0[0-9]:| 1[0-1]:' transactions | sort -u -k1,1 | wc -l
3

egrep ' 1[2-9]:| 2[0-3]:' transactions | sort -u -k1,1 | wc -l
1
```

Comment: So I have to split the transactions into 2 parts? Then do a count and then divide them?

Comment: What? No. The `transactions` is your example file. No need to split.

Comment: I have to iterate that a unique transaction is one that occurs for an individual  for morning and afternoon. that would count as one transaction

Comment: maulinglawns, according to your code, youre getting the morning ones an evening ones seperately. Then youre counting morning first then evening.

Comment: maulinglawns, I think youre onto something. If I use your suggestion to get the morning ones and evening ones, I can create two files. I can then join them by the userid and will get something like the following.

127890 2016-07-06 10:23:00 13:00:00. 

I can then get my count.

I will have to verify this since Ive already been able to accomplish the task. The only drawback is that my way takes 50 minutes to process.

I will confirm the numbers and let you know.